# MVC EditorFor property name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Has anyone written or is there a way to invoke EditorFor using a property name instead of using an expression.

```
EditorFor("Code")
```

as opposed to

```
EditorFor(_ => _.Code)
```

I want to write something more generic. Invoking EditorFor by creating an expression is proving tiresome, and I cannot believe there is not a better way.

This doesn't work.

```
var root = Expression.Parameter(Model.GetType(), "_");                
var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(root, property), root);
var ef = (Expression<Func<Product, string>>) expr;
var method = typeof(EditorExtensions).GetMethod("EditorFor", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new[] {typeof(HtmlHelper<>), typeof(Expression<Func<,>>)}, null);
```

method is always null, I have tried a lot of things.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `Editor` method is what you are after: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editor.aspx

Comment: It's not actually ideal because I ideally want all the data annotations fetched from the property, but it sort of works. I had to write some code for the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me get this straight.  You want to use method that is explicitly designed to use expressions, for the purpose of making them strongly typed.. and you want it to not be strongly typed?

Why not simply use the non-strongly typed version then?

The purpose of the "For" methods is to make them strongly typed.  It's confusing why you would want to use a For type but not use it for what's it's designed for.

Comment: I am looking for a non strongly typed version.
I don't want to roll my own or write all the template stuff myself (which is internal).